# Перспективы С++ разработчика

Tags: c#, java, c++

Доброго времени суток всем.

Как думаете, какие ныне перспективы у разработчика на языке С++?

Имеет ли смысл дальше продолжать стезю совершенствования в этом направлении?

Все меньше и меньше проектов создается на этом языке, вакансий меньше с каждым годом, огромный спрос имеют C# и Java.

Может имеет все-таки смысл переучиться на более современные языки?

Что думаете по этому поводу?

Comment: @Fike, а если умрут? Начинать с позиции C# trainee будучи сорокалетним дядькой? Какая-то не очень заманчивая перспектива, если честно.

Comment: @SoloMio, не просто если, а рано или поздно умрут. Но это произойдет далеко не единомоментно. PHP потихоньку вот умирает, скорее всего за этим будет новый расцвет, когда наконец движок перепишут и коммьюнити напишет все пакеты, какие только могут быть, но все равно это ощущается и народ валит на другие языки, причем не первый год такая ситуация.  
Я тут еще собирался словоблудить, но вернусь к своим же словам:

> Но тут такая штука, что ответить на этот вопрос за вас не может никто.

Если чувствуете, что боитесь за свое положение, начинайте переходить сейчас, конечно.

Comment: @SoloMio, не настолько уж эти языки отличаются друг от друга, чтобы так беспокоиться

(начиная с некоторого уровня Вы сами осознаете, что "все швейные машинки похожи друг на друга").

Вероятно пока Вы путаете язык с библиотеками/frameworks (но,  джентльменский набор контейнеров и алгоритмов всюду примерно похож).

 А  в каждой предметной области все равно будут свои и при переходе из одной области программирования в другую их придется изучать (независимо от познаний в языке).

Comment: @avp, я то это как раз понимаю, но вот как объяснить это работодателю, котрому нужно "знание" Hibernate и "3 года" Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@SoloMio](/users/10292/solomio)](/users/10292/solomio), этот вопрос возникает тут (с разными языками) в среднем раз в неделю-две. Но тут такая штука, что ответить на этот вопрос за вас не может никто. Если вы любите плюсы и готовы учиться день и ночь, то вы в один момент придете к статусу гуру, который уже не ищет работу (потому что работа ищет его по несколько раз на дню). Если вас интересует легкий заработок без особого напряга, оформления кода и тестирования, то можно и вордпрессы на PHP пилить.
Сами плюсы в ближайшие десять лет точно никуда не умрут, как и чистый си.

Comment: Все написано верно, но здесь есть одна проблема: из 1000 девелоперов, хорошо если вырастет один гуру - так что шансы так себе :)

Answer (score 3):

В целом да, перспектива не очень - С++ постепенно вытесняется более простыми и надежными языками, плюс к тому же в последнее время есть существенный уклон в сторону web и мобильных приложений, где главенствуют другие языки. Но с другой стороны вам же никто не мешает совершенствоваться сразу в двух (трех, четырех и тд) областях. Даже если вы будете C#-программистом, знание С++ точно не помешает, а иногда даже позволит получать больше, или рассматривать более широкий круг вакансий

Comment: Интересный оброт: надежный язык )) Надежно не дает программисту писать ненадежный код?

Comment: под надежностью я подразумевал наличие сборки мусора (все-таки отсутствие необходимости освобождения ресурсов позволяет писать более надежный код) и более обширная стандартная библиотека на все случаи жизни без необходимости писать на каждый чих свои (ненадежные) велосипеды или пользоваться чужими

Comment: @DreamChild скромные у Вас запросы в части надёжности. Кстати, у php вроде с библиотекой неплохо. И malloc я там не заметил

Comment: >скромные у Вас запросы в части надёжности

ну я же не сказал, что они исчерпываются этими двумя пунктами) 

>Кстати, у php вроде с библиотекой неплохо

если уж говорить про php, то и недостатков в нем можно накопать достаточно

Comment: @DreamChild недостатков у любого инструмента можно найти немало. А в части надёжности мне как-то больше нравится строгая статическая типизация. С алгебраическими типами данных

Comment: @DreamChild, знаете кого-нибудь, кому бы удавалось совмещать несколько направлений?

Comment: @SoloMio не могу сказать, что таких людей пруд пруди, но вообще да, знаю

Answer (score 3):

А Вы знаете, что до сих пор востребованы (и очень хорошо оплачиваются) специалисты по Коболу? Важен не инструмент, а степень владения им. Но если уж собрались куда-то уходить, советую Objective-C. После C++ он покажется раем. Будете игрушки для iOS стряпать, как горячие пирожки. Некоторые на этом миллионы сделали (речь об индивидуальных разработчиках).

Comment: [2 вакансии][1]  месячной давности на всю Россию и ближнее зарубежье - это "востребованы"? (нет, конечно hh - это еще не весь рынок труда, но ситуация более чем показательна)

А 1700 долларов за разработчика с опытом от трех лет это по-вашему "очень хорошо оплачиваются"? Тогда уж можно сказать, что охотник на мамонтов - отличная профессия. Во всяком случае предложений ненамного меньше. 

[1]:http://hh.ru/applicant/searchvacancyresult.xml?orderBy=0&compensationCurrencyCode=RUR&searchPeriod=30&text=cobol&itemsOnPage=20&

Comment: Специалисты по Коболу оплачиваются хорошо, но, скорее всего, не так хорошо, как во времена аферы Y2K. Только вот вопрос -- сколько их надо? Площадь резерваций для них ограничена. И новичок туда не влезет -- негде опыт набрать.

Comment: Значение имеет не "площадь резервации", а плотность населения? Джавистов нужны миллионы, а на рынке труда - десятки миллионов. Коболистов нужны тысячи, а на рынке - сотни. Вот и думайте.

Comment: >Коболистов нужны тысячи, а на рынке - сотни. Вот и думайте

а факты, подтверждающие это, есть, или это голословная болтовня? Как показывает ссылка, приведенная мною выше, на просторах одной шестой части суши коболистов нужно всего две штуки (может побольше, но ненамного), а зарплата в 1700 долларов - совсем не предел мечтаний (программист на Java/C# может получать и больше). Вероятно, в масштабах всего мира счет действительно идет на тысячи, но это уже совсем другая история. Плюс к тому же как правильно заметил @alexlz - "новичок туда не влезет "

Comment: Не влезет, не влезет, успокойтесь. Пилите свои Java/C#, они золотые.

P.S. Угадайте, сколько вакансий нейрохирурга на хаха.ру? Один штучка. Расскажите этому человеку, благодаря которому некоторые люди (попав в аварию, например) не стали трупами или, хуже того - овощами, обузой для родных, что у него совершенно ненужная, бесполезная профессия.

Да, для того, чтобы стать нейрохирургом, совершенно недостаточно прочесть книжку. И их ошибки не исправит сениор. Новичок туда не влезет. Ведь всем известно, что нейрохирурги получают свои знания в виде откровения с небес. Они никогда не были новичками.

Comment: отсутствие фактов, демагогия и притянутые за уши  аналогии? Весьма ожидаемо

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias

Последнее можно заменить на "Систематическая ошибка согласованности", если на английском читать неохота. Но это не одно и то же, и на англ интереснее

Comment: @DreamChild, есть очень много направлений программирования, которые вы не найдете на открытых рынках вакансий и приводить пруфы по которым довольно сложно. Так что доводы @VadimTukaev не так далеки от истины.

Что касается именно Кобола, пожалуйста(статья, ссылки, комментарии к статье довольно свежие): http://habrahabr.ru/post/139573/ Можно найти еще немало занятной информации, если постараться.

Comment: весьма занятное чтиво. Но опять же не более, чем демагогия и поиск отдаленных аналогий, не имеющих существенного отношения к обсуждаемому вопросу

Comment: Вы это за 4 минуты прочитали и поняли? Как я Вам завидую.

Кстати, когда человек СРАЗУ отрицает свои психологические проблемы - это обычно признак того, что они ещё серьёзнее, чем казалось сначала. Любой нормальный человек призадумается, быстренько проведёт что-то вроде самосканирования. А вдруг я действительно что-то не так сделал или сказал? Что-то недопонял или глупость сморозил? За одним исключением -http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0

Да-да, это демагогия..

Comment: @VadimTukaev, ну серьёзно, что вы на личности-то переходите?

В любом случае перспективы хорошо устроиться и жить сладко больше у java/c#.

Comment: @VadimTukaev сравнивать программиста на коболе с крутым нейрохирургом? Нехило. Учитывая объём коболовских исходников, там больше требуется бронированная задница, чем в других языках. Ареал кобола невелик и постоянно сокращается. Помню году в 2007 были статьи о том, что для Air Canadian делается система резервирования авиабилетов на персоналках (Кобол минус). И в других областях уйдут...

Answer (score 3):

[[@DreamChild](/users/10162/dreamchild)](/users/10162/dreamchild) прав - я помню лет 20 назад, когда плюсы только-только начинались найти работу со знанием плюсов было не то что просто, а очень просто. Сейчас уже все изменилось. Я бы сформулировал нынешнюю тенденцию так: на одних плюсах выжить сложно. Плюсы хороши только как добавка к основному функционалу: шарп или джава.

Comment: Всё правильно.

Answer (score 2):

копипаст с холивара "Java vs C++" (в данном контексте C# аналогичен Java)

первое что нужно понимать что для каждой задачи свой инструмент, и особенно нужно помнить что инструмент можно применять не по назначению.
скажем отвёрткой можно забивать гвозди, ей даже можно пользоваться как стамеской или долото, но она для этого не предназначена и используя нормальный инструмент вы будете куда производительнее.

так например на Java в сравнении с C++ проще и быстрее писать кросс платформенные приложения или много поточные приложения и при этом они будут работать быстрее C++, но зато когда дело касается железок или объёмной работы над памятью то на С++ писать быстрее и проще и работать будет быстрее чем Java.

а весь цимес в том что не надо говорить "Java" или "C++", надо говорить "Java" и "C++", за счёт того что есть JNI вы спокойно можете вынести все нагруженные вычисления в С\С++, а в Java оставить всё остальное, и получить лучшее из двух миров.